# Raspberry Pi 4 auxillary SPI mode 1 data on wrong clock edges

Tags: pi-4, spi, pigpio

I know it is a known issue that modes 1 & 3 do not work on the rpi aux spi. I gave it a try anyway on an rp400 and found some interesting results. Am currently using pigpio via python. This image ( [image: rpi_aux_spi_capture] ) is a capture of the aux spi in mode 0 and mode 1 where I'm sending out `[ 0b00011100, 0b10000101, 0b01010101 ]`. For mode 0, the data is centered on the rising edge of the clock as expected. For mode 1, where the same data is being sent out, things look funky. In mode 1, data is meant to be clocked in on the falling edge of the clock. But it appears the MOSI data is being sent out one clock pulse too early. If it were shifted left by one clock pulse the data would align with the falling edge of the clock. For reference, this image ( [image: rpi_main_spi_capture_m1] ) is a capture of the main spi in mode 1 where the mosi data is sent out on the falling edge of the clock as it should.

I feel there is a solution to this issue with simple hardware. Some flip flops maybe to delay the mosi by that one clock pulse. Ima have to think about it, unless someone here has some ideas : ) Maybe there is a way to fix this on the rpi itself.

Also of note, on the aux spi, each byte of clock pulses are not contiguous as they are on the main spi. I'm not sure its a problem but is curious.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this. Either on the pi itself or with an external bit of hardware.